# getting remote ip from local ip

Tags: python, ip-address

given a local side IP address(ip): u'1.1.1.1/32'  #unicode format

how to get the remote side ip?  (which will be 1.1.1.2)

logic:

if local ip is even, remote ip will be local ip + 1

else, local ip - 1

i was trying something like this:

```
ip_temp = int(ip.replace('/32','').split('.')[-1])
if ip_temp % 2 == 0:
    remote = ip + 1
else:
    remote = ip - 1
remote_ip = <replace last octet with remote>
```

I looked into ipaddress module but couldnt find anything useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Python socket utilities require that the Remote IP Be a tuple with a string and port number (integer).  For example:

```
import socket
address = ('127.0.0.1', 10000)
sock.connect(address)
```

For your case, you have most of the logic required.  However you need to determine what to do with the cases of X.X.X.0 and X.X.X.255.
The full code to do what you want is:

```
ip = '1.1.1.1/32'

# Note Drop the cidr notation as it is not necessary for addressing in python
ip_temp = ip.split('/')[0]
ip_temp = ip_temp.split('.')
# Note this does not handle the edge conditions and only modifies the last octet
if int(ip_temp[-1]) % 2 == 0:
    remote = int(ip_temp[-1]) + 1
else:
    remote = int(ip_temp[-1]) -1
remote_ip = ".".join(ip_temp[:3]) + "." + str(remote)
```